# Filtering and removing with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I have some trouble with filtering in jQuery:

```
<div>content: content: {"bla":"test","IMPORTANT"}</div>

  <button>Remove</button>
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("div").remove(":contains('content: content: {\"bla\":\"test\",\"')");
    });

</script>
```

So, onClick the whole div is being removed, I only want to remove the specified part, how can that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: .remove() will remove the element in your selector from the DOM. In this case all divs $("div")
.empty() will clear the content of the element but keep the node in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the div always comes in the same fashion, the following code will make a solution

```
    $("button").click(function () {
      var string = $("div").text();
        var arr = string.split(":");
        var arr1 = arr[3].split(",");
        var string1 = (arr1[1].replace("\"","")).replace("\"}","");
    $("div").text(string1);
    });
```

Check the demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Gcy9/)
**EDITED FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Gcy9/1/

Comment: Now that's really cool, but if the text is more complicated, I can't get it to filter the right part, any idea? Text: finish: prove: {"ident":"norm","prim":wrong,"text":"IMPORTANT"}

Comment: does IMPORTANT always comes at the end or sometimes there will be no IMPORTANT in the string ? ?

Comment: IMPORTANT is variable, there will be some different text everytime, but always in this position, all the rest will stay as shown.

Comment: Well now this code will solve your problem for sure . . Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coosal/2Gcy9/2/

Comment: or you can check this one as well . . very shortcut using regex . . http://jsfiddle.net/coosal/2Gcy9/3/

Comment: Great! Thank you very much so far, the jsfiddle.net/coosal/2Gcy9/2 is amazing! Last thing: Putting the final result (IMPORTANT) in a variable. I tried to use "finalString" etc. but I couldn't get an output, any idea?

Comment: show me the code after this IMPORTANT is separated from the string . .

Comment: I used exactly this script: jsfiddle.net/coosal/2Gcy9/2. But I edited this line: /*$("#scan-result").*/ var final = text(finalString, "");        but then I can't document.write(final); the "IMPORTANT" text.

Comment: write the code in jsfiddle and pass me the link . . i am confused with the code you provided just now

Comment: I need to use the variable "finalString" in other scripts of that document to use the "IMPORTANT" value further. I tried to make finalString globally available (removing the var), but unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove what's inside the div then select the div and then set its contents to the empty string using `text()`.

```
$("div").text("");
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently you want to keep part of the text which is there. To do that, you can use a regular expression to capture just the text that you want. To build off of Mark's answer:

```
$div = $("div");
str = $div.text()
str = str.replace(/.*?,"(.*)"\}$/, "$1");
$div.text(str)
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAM8C/)

Comment: I only want, that the part "IMPORTANT" stays there, the rest should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do some string manipulation on the contents of that div. Then update the text of the div with your results. Example:

```
$div = $("div:contains('content: content: {\"bla\":\"test\",\"')")
str = $div.text()
str = str.replace(/your regex goes here/, "")
$div.text(str)
```

Comment: This should work, determining the correct regex will be the difficult part. To do that you should have a good idea of the structure of the text within the div and where the IMPORTANT data lives inside that.

Comment: I tried it like that: '$div = $("#mydiv:contains('text')")
 str = $div.text()
 str = str.replace(/your regex goes here/, "removed")
 $div.text(str)' nothing happens, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What does your regex look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("button").click(function () {

  $("div:contains('content: content: {\"bla\":\"test\",\"')").text("");

 });
```